# Region being overridden by managed credentials when configuring bash script to deploy resources to specified AWS region,

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a bash script that I run on an AWS EC2 instance (that runs Cloud9 as a development environment), to bootstrap AWS resources for the environment (in this case, my sandbox). I'm configuring the region I'd like to deploy to like this:

```
aws configure set region "ap-southeast-1"
REGION=$(aws configure get region)
echo $REGION
```

This isn't correctly setting the $REGION variable. Using `set region ...` correctly sets the region in ~/.aws/config file on the EC2 instance. My EC2 instance uses AWS managed credentials, which means that my own local AWS region is being stored in the `~/.aws/credentials` file on the EC2 instance, which overrides the `config` file, so `aws configure get region` returns the region specified in the `credentials` file. Is there a way of setting and getting the region in an AWS EC2 instance when using managed credentials?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please view the [order of precedence](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-quickstart.html#cli-configure-quickstart-precedence) for setting AWS credentials. Note that running `aws configure` just creates the credentials file, which is the the 6th item in the precedence list. I suggest using environment variables, the 2nd precedence item.

Comment: I agree,  `export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION="ap-southeast-1"` should solve it.